# LBP not working for texture matching

Tags: matlab, image-processing, textures, histogram

After seeing few papers where they had used LBP for texture recognition,
I am implemented a simple LPB and used bhattacharya distance to get a score for the similarity.
But the the score is not good enough, for completely different textures. Am i doing any mistake in the code ?or LBP is not a good measure for texture.

```
    function LBP()

    clc;
    im=imread('bark1.jpg');
    subplot(2,2,1);imshow(im);



     [r c]=size(im);
     h1=tex_lpb(im,r,c);
      subplot(2,2,2);plot(h1 );
    im_2=imread('t_shirt.jpg');
    im_2=rgb2gray(im_2);
     subplot(2,2,3);imshow(im_2);

     [r c]=size(im_2);
     h2=tex_lpb(im_2,r ,c );

     subplot(2,2,4);plot(h2);

     weight=sum(sqrt(h1.*h2))


    end




    function h= tex_lpb(im,r,c)

      im_lpb=zeros(r,c);
    for i=2:r-1

        for j=2:c-1
        a=[];
        %checking with the 8 nieghbours

        %N-W
            if(im(i,j)>im(i-1,j-1))
                a=[a 0];
            else
                a=[a 1];
            end

         %N   
            if(im(i,j)>im(i-1,j))
                a=[a 0];
            else
                a=[a 1];
            end

           %N-E 
            if(im(i,j)>im(i-1,j+1))
                a=[a 0];
            else
                a=[a 1];
            end

            %E
            if(im(i,j)>im(i,j+1))
                a=[a 0];
            else
                a=[a 1];
            end


            %S-E
            if(im(i,j)>im(i+1,j+1))
                a=[a 0];
            else
                a=[a 1];
            end

            %S
            if(im(i,j)>im(i+1,j))
                a=[a 0];
            else
                a=[a 1];
            end

            %S-W
            if(im(i,j)>im(i+1,j-1))
                a=[a 0];
            else
                a=[a 1];
            end

            %W
            if(im(i,j)>im(i,j-1))
                a=[a 0];
            else
                a=[a 1];
            end

      b=0;
      dec=8;

%changing into decimal
      for k=0:7
          b=a(dec)*(2^k)+b;
          dec=dec-1;
      end
      b;
        im_lpb(i,j)=b;
        end
    end


    h=hist_vec(im_lpb);% getting histogram




    end

    function h=hist_vec(im_lpb)

    [r c]=size(im_lpb);

    h=zeros(1,256);
    for i=1:r
        for j=1:c
            h(1,im_lpb(i,j)+1)=h(1,im_lpb(i,j)+1)+1;
        end
    end

    h=h/sum(h);
    end
```

Image dataset

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: ... so what's your question?

Comment: I got better results with gabor filters.

Comment: @GilLevi: Which is language that you use to implement Gabor filter? Can you share it to me via email?

Comment: @user8264, I used Matlab to implement Gabot filters. Unfortunately, I can't share it as it belongs to the company in which I work.